# How to position angular material button at bottom of div while maintaining width?

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design

I am having trouble positioning my angular material button at the bottom of my div.

The div looks like this:

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="10px"
    fxLayoutAlign="center">

    <mat-card>
       </mat-card-header>
          HEADER CONTENT
       </mat-card-header>

       <mat-card-content fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center">
           <form>

              <div>
                 ...
              </div>
              
              <button type="submit" mat-raised-button>Save</button>
              <button type="submit" mat-raised-button>Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" mat-raised-button id="deleteProj">Delete</button>
           
           </form>
     
       </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Which results in the bottom of the `div` looking like:

[image]

I want to move the "Delete Project" button to the bottom of this div. I have tried the following:

```css
#deleteProj {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This moves the button but changes the width of the button:

[image]

When I change the width of the button to 100% it extends beyond the width of the parent div:

```css
#deleteProj {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to control layout inside the `form` element and group all of the first items together and the delete button separate. Something like:

```
<form fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch">

    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">

        <div>
            ...
        </div>

        <button type="submit" mat-raised-button>Save</button>
        <button type="submit" mat-raised-button>Cancel</button>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button id="deleteProj">Delete</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Tried this (and some minor variation) and it didn't change the original layout unfortunately

Comment: Put your code on Stackblitz.